# "Умирать придётся, не узнав, от чего" - правильно ли написано ОТ ЧЕГО?

Tags: орфография

"Умирать придётся, не узнав, от чего" - правильно ли написано ОТ ЧЕГО? Это предлог+местоимение или же здесь это наречие?

Answer (score 1):

***Умирать придётся, не узнав от чего.***

1. В таких сочетаниях обычно указывается причина, то есть местоимение имеет конкретное предметное значение. Тогда предлог пишется раздельно.

Например:

*Посреди города можно умереть от голода, можно от жажды.*

*Такая бодрая была, весёлая… Умерла! От чего же?*

2. Вторую запятую желательно не ставить, это правило Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Пункт 4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.); Не знаю почему, но я его не понимал (Триф.);

Comment: А вот что-то нигде не описано примыкание одиночного союзного слова к деепричастному обороту либо к другой обособленной конструкции. Да? Запятая не требуется перед "от", но требуется после деепричастия. Это одна из уязвимостей правил.

Comment: Деепричастие - это форма глагола, и оно вполне способно выполнять функцию опорного слова по отношению к придаточному изъяснительному предложению. Интонационно же здесь все четко: УмирАть придётся, // не узнав от чеЕо.  А три запятые – это уже перебор.

Comment: Хотите  лирическое отступление на тему деепричастий. Вчера моя знакомая сдавала аттестацию в своем редакционном холдинге по информативному стилю. Она спросила у меня, что такое отглагольное наречие.  Я ответила, что такой термин обычно не используется, но, может, это наречие, образованное от отглагольного прилагательного (отвечать путано). Нет! Это у горе-педагога – деепричастие!

Comment: Там с паузой и ударением звучит лучше. Почему три запятые? Две. Хм, оказывается, это деепричастия, которые совсем или почти совсем лишились оттенков глагольности: https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tipyi-otglagolnyih-narechiy-48113.html

Comment: Я хотела сказать: не следует делить маленькое предложение запятыми на три части. Двух фонетических фраз вполне достаточно, на схеме я показала их границу.
 Спасибо за информацию про «отглагольные наречия». Статья Виноградова написана в 1947 году, годы жизни  (1895–1969). Теперь понятно, откуда и что. Вероятно,  этот неадекватный чиновник, принимавший у главредов аттестацию, его ровесник, не иначе. Термин этот,  как я полагаю, в современном языкознании не используют (не закрепился он в лингвистике). Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не знаю, терминами почти не интересуюсь.